# Market mix modelling with R

Tags: r, references, marketing

Can somebody give me references (book/online resource) on using R for Marketing Mix Modelling?

Comment: this question was asked on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681630/market-mix-modeling-with-r). Coincidentally, the book referenced [there](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Amarket+mix+modeling%2Cn%3A!1000%2Cn%3A3&bbn=1000&keywords=market+mix+modeling&ie=UTF8&qid=1302897164&rnid=1000) is still applicable here.

Comment: Thanks Chase! I post it the same ques here expecting somebody gives me some more resources. I got one (Bayesian) & that book is good.

Answer (score 5):

Marketing Mix Modelling is regression analysis with two differences. Variables are transformed to incorporate the memory effect of advertising, i.e. adstock effect, as well as diminishing returns of advertising.

I have created a simple tutorial on how to do Marketing Mix Modelling "MMM" in R: 
https://analyticsartist.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/marketing-mix-modeling-explained-with-r/

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the R part, which was not cited at commentaries above:

[bayesm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesm/bayesm.pdf) R package, published nearly one year after this question was posted.

Title: Bayesian Inference for Marketing/Micro-econometrics.
Author: Peter Rossi .